# simple 3d interpolation like maybe sponge deformation or heat conduction

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, interpolation, simulation

I have faced with a problem which I have no clue even to find a proper keyword to search. So I ask a question here to expect even some keyword or tag.

The background is very complex. But the result I wanna achieve can be described as a simple scene.

Suppose I have a cube made of glass. The cube is full of sponge. And there's a person in the sponge. Now the person does some movement or action. Then of course the sponge is deformed. This person is described as a geometry. I know the person's original pose, which means I know the original geometry. And I also know the deformed geometry. I prefer to describe the sponge as points or grids in the cube. I know that finite element method can do this accurately. But Is there any interpolation method to calculate how the sponge's points will be? 
I donot expect any accurate deformation. I just expect that some falloff to show the pinch or stretch.

Any keyword are welcome. Thx so much.

Comment: You could model the system as connected springs. If you can specify some of the sponge's grid points due to the moving person (i.e. boundary constraints), you can set up an appropriate system and solve for the unknown grid positions. A simple start might be the graph Laplacian.

Comment: @NicoSchertler You are describing the basis of finite elements!

Comment: Suppose the "person" is a tiny ball moving towards right. The sponge gets deformed not only in that direction, but also all around, more in the nearby, less far from the ball. If you want to simulate it right you need FEM or a complex model with lots of springs, or a deformation sampler that fades off as distance to peturbation grows.

Comment: Thx for ur comments. I know there's some math functions falling off well along distance. But the problem is I may have too many constriants? Usually the cube I emntioned is 64*64*64. All points on the shell of grid are constraints as their move vectors are (0,0,0). And it's about 64*64*6 points. All points of the person geometry are constraints and it's around several hundreds. I think there's too much contraints to interpolate. But maybe it's not. I will do some experiment first. thx u guys.

Answer (score 0):

'cause the structure of my scene is fixed, I choose simple KNN to implement this feature. As structure is fixed, I create a kdtree at the very beginning. Then deform other points based on KNN.